# iOS build does not install through windows iTunes

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I have a problem installing my app using iTunes on windows. On mac works fine but on windows the installation goes almost by the end and then an error appears "Failed to install". 
I am using the same provisioning profile on the device as the one that I am using to build the project.

Does anybody know why is this happening?

Device used: iPad 2 - OS 6.0

Any information would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems when deploying my app to testers. Sometimes, the installation over iTunes just fails even though both the .ipa and provisioning profiles are made correctly.

So we decided to switch to over-the-air deployment with [Testflight](https://testflightapp.com) and everything worked fine. Its easy to set up, free and it solves a lot of headaches for iOS testing.

Comment: I'm also happy with TestFlight — it's much easier to send builds with it.

Comment: I will go for TestFlight as I also heard good thoughts about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the console log while doing the install - usually it shows much more details on these occasions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using right provisioning profile and want to install ad-hoc build from windows, apple provides iPhone configuration utility that will enable you to install it on the desired device here is the [download link](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1466?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)